# Adobe AIR CameraUI overlay image

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, air

I'm using ActionScript and other Adobe applications to develop a small game kind of application targeting ios and Android via AIR 2.7.

My requirement is to launch camera while overlaying an image on it, so that user can take a picture of a person, within the boundaries showed in the overlay image.

Launching Camera, saving it cameraroll all working fine with CameraUI, but don't see any option to set overlay image.

is AIR native extension only way? any alternative approaches please

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

not 100% sure if the same for android, but using iOS you can get the video as if you were getting from a webcam in normal flash and attach it to a video instance.

```
var cam:Camera = Camera.getCamera(); 
if (cam != null) 
{ 
    var vid:Video = new Video(cam.width, cam.height); 
    vid.attachCamera(cam); 
    addChild(vid); 
}
```

works fine on iPhone and iPad